# How can i set basic auth header to opentelemetry exporter?

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

Here is my configuration.yml file

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:5555

exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug
  otlphttp:
    endpoint: https://tempo-dev.com
extensions:
  health_check:

service:
  extensions: [health_check]
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [otlphttp]
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [otlphttp,logging]
```

When open telemetry pushes traces and metrics to tempo its giving 401

Want to pass auth header  when exporting traces to tempo

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need basic auth header.

Minimalistic option is to use `headers` directly - you need to create header value manually - e.g. base64 your `username:password`, e.g:

```
otlphttp:
  endpoint: <tempo:port>
  headers:
    authorization: Basic <base64(username:password)> # you must provide raw string, e.g.: authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

More convenient option is [basicauth extension](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/extension/basicauthextension). Of course you must have that extension available.

```
extensions:
  basicauth:
    client_auth: 
      username: username
      password: password

exporters:
  otlphttp:
    endpoint: <tempo:port>
    auth:
      authenticator: basicauth
```

Comment: I have tried the first solution  it does not convert the username and password to base64 it attaches a header like this when trace and matrics are pushing to tempo 

Received a POST request to /v1/metrics
Request Headers: {
  host: 'localhost:4318',
  'user-agent': 'OpenTelemetry Collector/0.87.0 (linux/amd64)',
  'content-length': '2217',
  authorization: 'Basic base64(username:password-value)',
  'content-encoding': 'gzip',
  'content-type': 'application/x-protobuf',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip'
}

Comment: Also tried the second solution and get the below error 

* error decoding 'extensions': unknown type: "basicauth" for id: "basicauth" (valid values: [pprof zpages memory_ballast health_check])
2024/01/02 10:22:54 collector server run finished with error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 1 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'extensions': unknown type: "basicauth" for id: "basicauth" (valid values: [pprof zpages memory_ballast health_check])

Comment: @parmeshwarchavan everything what is in `<..>` is your responsibility to create - there is no `base64` - you have to do it - it must be raw string. `unknown type: "basicauth"` - as I said - you must have that extension, apparently you don't have it, so you can't use it.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a basic authentication value dynamically based on the username and password?i mean i don't want to hardcode it

Comment: how can i add that extension to open telemetry.

i have run the open telemetry through the docker

FROM otel/opentelemetry-collector:0.87.0

COPY configuration.yaml /etc/configuration.yaml
CMD ["--config=/etc/configuration.yaml"]

Comment: @parmeshwarchavan please check documentation of your collector (you don't need to hardcoded anything - you can use env variable there for example - but please don't ask here how - check documentation or create new question). This is not a chat, where you should be asking many questions. Please accept also an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For using the basic auth extension needs a   otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib image